# Send and Receive 'Post' data

Tags: c#, asp.net

Wonder if someone could assist me please, what I'm trying to achieve is to send data from one site to another: So in my 'sending' site I have a page that that runs the following:

```
    string message;
    message = "DATA DATA DATA DATA!!!";

    System.Net.WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://clt-umbraco.test.clt.co.uk/storereceive/?data-response");

    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Headers["X-Parse-Application-Id"] = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    request.Headers["X-Parse-REST-API-Key"] = "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb";
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes("{\"channels\": [\"\"], \"data\": { \"alert\": \" " + message + "\" } }");
    string result = System.Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
    Stream reqstr = request.GetRequestStream();
    reqstr.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    reqstr.Close();

    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    //jsonString.Text = response;
    reqstr = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(reqstr);
    jsonString.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

And on my receiving site/page I have the following on page load:

```
    string[] keys = Request.Form.AllKeys;
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
    {
        Response.Write(keys[i] + ": " + Request.Form[keys[i]] + "<br>");
    }
```

I can see that this page load event is firing but the Request.Form.Allkeys object is empty where I would hope it would contain the data from the sending page. Obviously I'm going drastically wrong somewhere....could someone help please??

Thanks,
Craig

Comment: are you sure the request is being processed successfully? what does `reader.ReadToEnd()` returns?

Comment: reader.ReadToEnd() receives the HTML of the 'receiving' page. So the request is being processed, there's just no data coming into the receiving page.

Answer (score 0):

That is because You are not posting a form, you are uploading raw data.

Set
    request.ContentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

And populate your post data as such:

```
Key1=value1&key2=value2
```

You should also consider encoding the values with HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode

If you still wan't to send raw data though, then at the server end, you should read the incoming data like: (instead of `Request.Form[]`)

```
byte[] requestRawData = Request.BinaryRead(Request.ContentLength);
```

Comment: Changing the contenttype as you suggesting worked (thanks!) so obviously I was reading the incoming 'data' incorrectly. Is there a way to receive the incoming raw data?

Comment: Cheers mucka, I shall give that a whirl